# Openshift hooks during gear restart

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

When I deploy my app with Jenkins or restart app with `app_ctl` `action_hooks` are executed. But when I restart application with `rhc app restart app_name` `actions_hooks` are not executed. I set up custom JVM parameters in `actions_hooks`. What I am doing wrong or how to solve this somehow? Using JBoss EWS 2.0 (Tomcat 7) cartridge.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an rhc app stop & rhc app start instead of restart, start/stop action hooks are not executed on a restart i believe.